# How to avoid a TooManyApplicationVersion exception on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Lately has anyone witnessed the

```
TooManyApplicationVersions Exception
```

on [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) console while deploying a new application version (war)? It's so annoying to see this message as it appears only after you have finished uploading the war.

I would be interested to know why this exception occurs and what precautions one should take to avoid such situations?

Comment: If it helps anyone, there is a nicely written article on how to use the AWS SDK to delete the obsolete/old application versions when the limit is about to exceed.
http://www.danmandle.com/blog/automatically-remove-old-aws-elastic-beanstalk-application-versions/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Cause

The exception you are seeing stems from reaching your respective account limits for [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/), see section *Errors* in [CreateApplicationVersion](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CreateApplicationVersion.html) *[paraphrased]*:

> - **TooManyApplicationVersions** - *The caller has exceeded the limit on the
>     number of application versions associated with their account.*
> - **TooManyApplications** - *The caller has exceeded the limit on the number of applications associated with their account.*

The current limits are outlined in the respective FAQ [How many applications can I run with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/#application-count):

> You can create up to 25 applications and **500 application versions**. By
>   default you can run up to 10 environments across all of your
>   applications. If you are also using AWS outside of Elastic Beanstalk,
>   you may not be [...] **If you need more resources, complete the AWS Elastic
>   Beanstalk request form and your request will be promptly evaluated.** *[emphasis mine]*

### Solution

As emphasized, AWS offers the usual escalation option and allows you to submit a [Request to Increase AWS Elastic Beanstalk Limits](http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/elasticbeanstalk-request/), if you really need that many application versions to be available for reuse still. Otherwise you might just delete older ones you will not use anymore and the problem should vanish accordingly.

Good luck!

Comment: I've experienced this too - is there any automated way to delete old versions? Or to set up version deletion policy of some sort?

Comment: @petr - nothing readily available from AWS that I know of, sorry.

Comment: Beanstalk now supports automatically deleting old versions based on a lifecycle policy. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 21):

Here's a one liner that uses the AWS CLI that will help you clear out old application versions:

`aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions --output text --query 'ApplicationVersions[*].[ApplicationName,VersionLabel,DateCreated]' | grep "2014-02" | while read app ver date; do aws elasticbeanstalk delete-application-version --application-name $app --version-label $ver --delete-source-bundle; done`

Replace the grep with whatever date, (2013, 2014-01, 2014-02-0, etc) you see fit.

Comment: Would be great if this command were improved to delete all applications version no deployed minus the previous applications versions deployed (To keep the last one in emergency case).

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the list of applications version with information if was deployed or not, but describe-application-versions doesn't provide such information. Something similar to Elastic Beanstalk web console that shows the list of applications versions detailing where were deployed each one.

Answer (score 15):

As of EB CLI 3.3, you can now run the following to clear out old versions:

```
$ eb labs cleanup-versions
```

By default this will cleanup to the last 10 versions and/or older than 60 days. Adding `--help`, outputs the following:

```
usage: eb labs cleanup-versions [options...]

Cleans up old application versions.

optional arguments:
--num-to-leave NUM    number of versions to leave DEFAULT=10
--older-than DAYS     delete only versions older than x days DEFAULT=60
--force               don't prompt for confirmation
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 3.7.8. This is what the AWS rep suggested also, but it simply doesn't work. He didn't know how to make it work either. Pretty on par for the platform.

Comment: Worked OK for me using EB CLI 3.20.6

Answer (score 13):

You're approaching maximum number of versions and need to delete old or unused ones.

In the current web console you can simply do it on the Application Versions tab of your Beanstalk environment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the piece of code that we use in our deploy script to delete the oldest application version.

```
console.log('Deleting oldest application version.');
params = {};
local.waitFor(function(done) {
    eb.describeApplicationVersions(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err, err.stack);
            local.abort('Could not retrieve the list of application version.');
        } else {
            // This is probably not needed as the list is already sorted but it is
            // not written anywhere that this will always be the case
            function compare(a,b) {
                if (a.DateCreated > b.DateCreated)
                    return -1;
                if (a.DateCreated < b.DateCreated)
                    return 1;
                return 0;
            }
            var applicationsVersion = data['ApplicationVersions'].sort(compare),
                oldestApplication   = applicationsVersion[applicationsVersion.length - 1],
                applicationName     = oldestApplication['ApplicationName'],
                versionLabel        = oldestApplication['VersionLabel'];
            params = {
                ApplicationName: applicationName, /* required */
                VersionLabel:    versionLabel,    /* required */
                DeleteSourceBundle: false /* Do not delete source bundle from S3 */
            };
            eb.deleteApplicationVersion(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err, err.stack);
                    local.abort('Could not delete the oldest application version. (' + versionLabel + ')')
                } else {
                    console.log('Successfully deleted the oldest application version. (' + versionLabel + ')');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Documentation for the Elastic Beantalk API (js): http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ElasticBeanstalk.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

**>>** The error only occurred with specific environments and/or applications. Other apps had no problems  with the deploy.

**>>** I did not exceed the default bean stalk quotas. I validated it by counting them and comparing with the default values

**environments count**

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments --output text --query 'Environments[*].[EnvironmentName]' | wc -l
```

**versions count**

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-application-versions --output text --query 'ApplicationVersions[*].[ApplicationName]'  | wc -l
```

**default values**

[image]

**>>** I also implemented an automated recycle like [update-application-resource-lifecycle](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/nikkei/nikkei-aws-eb)

**>>** I deleted several environments/versions but the error persisted

---

If you reach this line the only solution for me was to delete manually the environment and its versions. In my case the environment had only one version.

[image]