# PhpStorm suddenly stopped deploying to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, phpstorm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk from PhpStorm. It's been working all night, but I just tried to push to our server again, and now am getting this message:

Failed to deploy 'Project': com.viatra2.cloud.imported.remote.servers.util.ServerRuntimeException: com.intellij.openapi.vcs.VcsException: Error executing git push -f https://...

HEAD:refs/heads/master --

When I click on the link in the message box, it takes me to a blank webpage.

Any ideas on why it's no longer deploying?

Thanks!

Comment: Found it - ends up that you're only allowed 500 versions on Elastic Beanstalk, and that was what was throwing the error. Just need to go into your EB console and delete the versions.

Comment: You can add your own answer (in a few hours), and reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/9590979/6309